# inserting data into database table issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i wanna make register form.But i cant insert datas into my db table "yeni"
and get "Error....!!".I really need to solve this problem guys pls help me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoCNK.png

### registration.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#register").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var tc = $("#tc").val();
    var tel = $("#tel").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var cpassword = $("#cpassword").val();

    if (name == '' || tc == '' || tel == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
      alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
    }
    else if ((password.length) < 8) {
      alert("Password should atleast 8 character in length...!!!!!!");
    }
    else if (!(password).match(cpassword)) {
      alert("Your passwords don't match. Try again?");
    }
    else {
      $.post("sign.php", {
        name1: name,
        tc1:tc,
        tel1: tel,
        password1: password
      }, function(data) {
        if (data == 'You have Successfully Registered.....') {
          $("form")[0].reset();
        }
        alert(data);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

### sign.php

```
<?php
  $connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
  $db = mysql_select_db("babo", $connection); 

  $name = $_POST['name1']; // Fetching Values from URL.
  $tc = $_POST['tc1'];
  $tel = $_POST['tel1'];
  $password = sha1($_POST['password1']);

  $query = mysql_query("insert into yeni(adi, tc_no, password, tel) values ('$name', '$tc', '$password', '$tel')"); 

  if($query) {
    echo "You have Successfully Registered.....";
  } else {
    echo "Error....!!";
  }

  mysql_close ($connection);
?>
```

Comment: try  this `$query = mysql_query("insert into yeni(adi, tc_no, password, tel) values ('".$name."', '".$tc."', '".$password."' , '".$tel."')")`

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and have security issues. Please consider using `mysqli` or `PDO`. About your question, consider debugging what you have on `$_POST` and sanitizing your data before making your query.

Comment: @MayankVadiya it did not change anything :(

Comment: This code appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Oh, wait. Never mind. Security guidelines are something we only think about *after* we've fully developed oodles of application code using vulnerable patterns.

Answer (score 1):

1. As allready suggested use [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php) function in favor of mysql_ functions
2. You should use [prepered statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php)
3. To get a better starting point on whats actually wrong replace `echo "Error....!!";` with `echo mysqli_error($connection);`

Comment: @teemtzitrone ty mate i did what you adviced and it works! ty ty so much!